# Bid response status when it didn't win

Tags: prebid.js

Is there a way to detect why a bid did not win ?

From `pbjs.getBidResponses()` I can see each winning bid have `message: "rendered"` while the loosing bid don't but cannot find any status/reason why the other didn't win ? i.e either its timed out because response delayed or it has lowest CMP!

Answer (score 0):

In our [PubWise.io](http://pubwise.io) header bidding analytics product we look at the difference between win Events and Response events. Ultimately the DFP server determines if the item wins, so the response event does not have that info.